# Can I access the variable when function returns self?

Tags: python

A piece of code from the function "pipeline.py" is as follows

```
def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
    """Fit all the transforms one after the other and transform the
    data, then fit the transformed data using the final estimator.
    """
    Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    return self
```

It is called in main():

```
pl.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm not familiar about the usage of self. My question is, can I access the variable "Xt" without changing the function "fit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this specific instance -- it looks like you can do:

```
Xt, fit_params = pl._pre_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

...outside of the `fit` function to get `Xt`, and just ignore `fit_params`.

Thankfully, it looks like how the `fit` function calculates `Xt` is fairly straightforward -- it makes just a single call to a method. However, note that `_pre_transform` is marked as a "private" method -- by starting the method with an underscore, the authors of the library you're using have indicated that the method is nominally private, isn't part of the public API, and may change in future versions.

It also looks like the the method is modifying itself, so you should probably double-check to make sure that calling `_pre_transform` won't cause any side effects.

---

How did I know this would work?

Well, when you did `pl.fit(X_train, y_train)`, I knew that Python was going to internally re-write that to something like:

```
fit(pl, X_train, y_train)
```

That means that inside the `fit` method, `self` refers to `pl`, `X` refers to `X_train`, and `y` refers to `y_train`.

In general, when you do `my_obj.method(a, b)`, it's approximately the same thing as `method(my_obj, a, b)`. That means that `self` will typically be the same as `my_obj` (unless you're doing something really weird/doing metaprogramming).

Then, the very first line of the `fit` method was:

```
Xt, fit_params = self._pre_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
```

So, if `self -> pl`, `X -> X_train`, and `y -> y_train`, I knew that this line of code was actually doing:

```
Xt, fit_params = pl._pre_transform(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

I also knew that you could ignore `fit_params`, since you didn't provide any arguments apart from X_train and y_train:

```
Xt, fit_params = pl._pre_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

Well, there's nothing stopping us from calling this exact line of code outside the `fit` function -- it should behave correctly regardless of where it's called. So I did.

---

However, the answer to the more general question is 'no' -- just because the function uses 'self' doesn't mean that the variables inside the function are automatically available. The method has to either return `Xt`, or do something like `self.Xt = Xt` to add `Xt` as a field to the object.

Comment: Amazing, it works. I wonder how you can tell _pre_transform belongs to pl, and its inputs are X_train and y_train? I think "self" refers to pl here, is this correct?